# why are my PowerShell results repeating?

Tags: powershell

Good day,

PowerShell rookie here...

If I output to the screen like this:

```
    foreach($databasePermission in $database.EnumDatabasePermissions($user.Name))
{
    Write-Host $databasePermission.PermissionState $databasePermission.PermissionType "TO" $databasePermission.Grantee
}
```

I get this, which is what I want:

```
Grant CONNECT TO dbo
```

However, if I try to output to a text file like this:

```
    foreach($databasePermission in $database.EnumDatabasePermissions($user.Name))
{
    "$databasePermission.PermissionState $databasePermission.PermissionType TO $databasePermission.Grantee" | Out-File $filename
}
```

My results repeat like this:

```
[dbname] Database: cust_serv, Grant, CONNECT.PermissionState [dbname] Database: cust_serv, Grant, CONNECT.PermissionType TO [dbname] Database: cust_serv, Grant, CONNECT.Grantee
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you access properties of an object in a string, you have to enclose it in `$(...)`:

Look at the difference between

```
"$databasePermission.PermissionState"
```

and

```
"$($databasePermission.PermissionState)"
```

Answer (score 2):

Good way to construct long strings is to use string formatting. It is more readable ( atleast imo, since you don't have to do `$($...)` etc.):

```
"{0} {1} TO {2}" -f $databasePermission.PermissionState,$databasePermission.PermissionType,$databasePermission.Grantee
```